# Check if user has permision to truncate tables programmatically

Tags: mysql

I would like to check if a user has the permission to truncate tables in MySQL DB programmatically. This check needs to be done without any side effects.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TRUNCATE TABLE` needs to two table privileges: `Drop` and `DELETE` which stores in  `mysql.tables_priv` table, so you need to check if user has the both privileges. i.e.: this query shows which user has truncate permission on which table:

```
select user,table from mysql.tables_priv
where Table_priv like '%Delete%' and Table_priv like '%Drop%'
```

Answer (score 0):

`tables_priv` will only contain privileges not granted at a higher level.  If @hpns's answer turns up nothing, try:

```
SELECT `user`, `db` FROM `mysql`.`db` WHERE `Delete_priv` AND `Drop_priv`
```